Attic Insulation Options - Old House
I have a very old home built in the 20s in St. Louis area of Missouri. I am unable to get my HVAC to set a comfortable temperature in summer and winter. My AC runs most of the day in the summer and vice versa for winter. I usually even set the temps for 74/68 respectively.
Mostly I have narrowed down the issue to there being not enough insulation in the attic. Obvious answers to this are to add more (blown-in) or batt. However, when I purchased the house my inspection concluded the attic insulation to be vermiculite which the EPA says to assume contains asbestos. I have not gotten it tested and even if it were tested, I have read that vermiculite can cause many false negatives due to the nature of vermiculite itself.
So my question is if there are any options for me to add more insulation without having to remove the vermiculite? I assume adding blow-in insulation would disturb the asbestos and is a no-go. I was thinking a possibility of doing spray foam?
For reference my attic does not have roof ridge venting or soffit venting. I have 3 gable vents and also a whole house fan which I usually only use in spring and fall.

1920s house might not have any/poor vapour barrier also.  Wearing a good mask you can check the depth and if any barrier is under vermiculite.  If no barrier then can add one over the top before more insulation.  If a barrier then add a non vapour barrier like house wrap.  The walls are probably poorly insulated also, so should check them also.  If the vermiculite is deep, the walls might be the problem.

So, before you guess as to the problem, why not get a thermal camera to image the walls and roof? That will confirm exactly what is happening so you can target your use of money...

@Solar Mike I have never thought of doing this. Thank you. As crip659 pointed out it could also be lack of insulation in the walls. I have noticed a lot of heat on my western facing wall during the afternoon as that is where the couch sits. The current insulation sits about an inch over the ceiling joists in the attic. Maybe most of the issue is the walls.

1920s insulation in the walls might be newspaper or loose bricks if any, if it has not been upgraded since then.
